# yii2 validation rules on update

Tags: php, validation, model, yii2

I have a model and validation rules for it:

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
 ...
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['username', 'password', 'email'], 'required', 'on' => 'insert'],
        [['password', 'email'], 'required', 'on' => 'update'],
    ]
}
```

Actually the code produces no validators. When I remove 'on' section, everything goes well.

Digging in official documentation and search thru The Web didn't help me to understand what is the issue, and why can't I have custom required fields sets for different actions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Scenario is not automaticaly setted by Yii2 ActiveRecord. If you need a specific scenario you must create it and assign in the model.

E.g. for update ...

```
public function scenarios()
{
    $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
    $scenarios['update'] = ['password', 'email'];//Scenario Values Only Accepted
    return $scenarios;
}
```

Also you can set scenario in your actionUpdate

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
   $model = $this->findModel($id);
   $model->scenario = 'update';
  ........
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works correctly. It's a pity the documentation looks a bit non-intuitive for me.